# Find covariance matrix of $\frac{f(x + y) }{x + y}$ function

Tags: probability-theory, variance, covariance

The conditions are [the same](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3241938/506648), but my task is to find covariance matrix. I only noticed that density function is symmetric so expected values, variance are also the same. But I don't know how to find covariance, variance in my case. I will be grateful for some ideas or tips.

Comment: What have you tried? You should calculate a couple of integrals, did you get them?

Comment: My density fucntion is $\frac{f(x + y)}{x + y}$. At least, I will need expected value. It will be $\int_{0}^{\infty} x (\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f(x + y)}{x + y} dy) dx $. What substitution I should use I dont know.

Comment: The same substitution used in the question you liked to.

Comment: Thank you, I've solved it! The topic can be closed.

Comment: Great! Go and post an answer to your own question!